# Converting a list to an array

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's assume that I have a list that I can access like `list[[i, j]]`

How can I convert it to an array such that:

`my_array[i, j] = list[[i, j]]`

In the simplest way (avoiding loops). Also, ideally shifting array index such that `my_array[i, j] = list[[i+1, j+1]]` (to have the `[0, 0]` of the array matching the first element from the "matrix" `[[1, 1]]`)

Comment: You shouldn't use an underscore in the name `my_array`. Also it's generally better to keep it as a list for efficient access. bill's answer is a good compromise because it keeps the list without copying it but provides the access pattern you want without creating unnecessary variables.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I do not see much necessity in the posted desired operation.

Answer (score 7):

What you're calling my_array may be thought of as a function, which you can assign like:

```
myfun[i_, j_] := list[[i, j]];
```

or, to shift the indices:

```
myfun[i_, j_] := list[[i+1, j+1]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomInteger[10, {4, 5}]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 4, 0, 7, 0}, {0, 8, 6, 0, 4}, {1, 8, 5, 1, 1}, {1, 3, 2, 10, 1}}
> ```

```
ClearAll[myArray]
myArray = Indexed[list, 1 + {##}] /. Indexed[_, ___] :> Undefined &;

{myArray[0, 1], myArray[3, 2], myArray[4, 6]}
```

> ```
>  {4, 2, Undefined}
> ```